# Mongoose Pull one element from a nested Array by ObjectID

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a `Schedule` Schema and I'm trying to an element from a nested `slotsPerDay` array.

```
const scheduleSchema =  mongoose.Schema({
    course_id: {{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'course' }}, 
    week_schedule: [{
        day: {type: String, required: true },
        slotsPerDay: [{type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'slots' }],
    }]
});
```

I'm trying to delete a certain slot ObjectID from the slotsPerDay array that's encapsulated inside the week_schedule array as follows.

```
 SchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate(
         {course_id: req.body.course_id},
         { "$pull": { "week_schedule": { "slotsPerDay": {"_id": req.body.slotID }}}}
 ,{new:true})
```

However, this query deletes the whole week_schedule array with all it's slots, not just the one mapping to the slotID given in query. Any help fixing that?

I tried  `{ "$pull": { "week_schedule.slotsPerDay": {"_id": req.body.slotID }}}`
but I get the error

> Cannot use the part (slotsPerDay) of (week_schedule.slotsPerDay) to
> traverse the element ({week_schedule: [ { slotsPerDay: [
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334a'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933349'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334b'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334c'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334d'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334e'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93334f'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933350') ], _id:
> ObjectId('5fe0266a72f7b53aac933364'), day: "Saturday" }, {
> slotsPerDay: [], _id: ObjectId('5fe0266a72f7b53aac933365'), day:
> "Sunday" }, { slotsPerDay: [], _id:
> ObjectId('5fe0266a72f7b53aac933366'), day: "Monday" }, { slotsPerDay:
> [ ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933356'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933357'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933359'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335a') ], _id:
> ObjectId('5fe0266a72f7b53aac933368'), day: "Wednesday" }, {
> slotsPerDay: [ ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335b'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335c'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335d'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335e'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac93335f'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933360'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933361'),
> ObjectId('5fe0263872f7b53aac933362') ], _id:
> ObjectId('5fe0266a72f7b53aac933369'), day: "Thursday" } ]})

Comment: Are you trying to remove a day from the `week_schedule` array or an element from a nested `slotsPerDay` array?

Comment: an element from a nested SlotsPerDay

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
SchemaModel.findOneAndUpdate(
     { course_id: req.body.course_id },
     { $pull: { "week_schedule.$[].slotsPerDay": req.body.slotID }},
     { new: true })
```

It uses the [all positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/), `$[]`. For all elements in the `week_schedule` array, it pulls elements from the nested `slotsPerDay` array with a value equal to `req.body.slotID`.